# What is an ideal way to get unique values into a multidimensional array in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have the following code, which populates my array nicely.  The problem is that some of the values are duplicates and I only want unique data.  I have seen examples for single-dimensional arrays, but nothing for a multi-dimensional array.

For my use here, the "A" column is an identifier and the "B" column is a name.  For example, "A2" may be "A1234" and "B2" would be "Air Rifle".  The code in the "A" column will always be unique to the description in the "B" column, so I only need to search duplicates in the "A" column; though, I would be curious about examples that worked each way.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

```
Sub testme()
    Dim myArray As Variant

    myArray = Range("A2:B20")
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23481700/deleting-duplicates-in-a-vba-array)?

Comment: And [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382431/loading-an-array-with-only-unique-values?lq=1)

Comment: @Ioannis, I could only get that to add the unique values as separate entries in a single-dimensional array.  I was able to use Alex P's entry and tweak it to work.  Thank you for your assistance though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check the comments from `Ioannis` and `Alex P` first.

This would work using a `dictionary` object:

```
Sub UniqueValuesOnly()
    Dim myArray As Variant, a As Integer
    Dim dict As Object

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    myArray = Range("A2:B20")

    For a = 1 To UBound(myArray, 1)
        If Not dict.Exists(myArray(a, 1)) Then
            dict.Add myArray(a, 1), myArray(a, 2)
        End If
    Next a

    For Each Key In dict
        Debug.Print Key, dict(Key)  //Let's print out the content to see if it worked...
    Next Key

    Set dict = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: This is fantastic.  I saw other examples with using a dictionary entry, but I did not understand how to add the second dimension to it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I took the link from `Alex P`'s comment from my question and tweaked to work.  I prefer the elegance of the dictionary entry, so I marked that as the answer, but I wanted to share the tweak in case it helps someone else.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim firstRow As Integer, lastRow As Integer, cnt As Integer, iCell As Integer
    Dim myArray()

    ReDim myArray(1, 0)
'    Debug.Print UBound(myArray)

    cnt = 0
    firstRow = 2
    lastRow = 20

    For iCell = firstRow To lastRow
        If Not IsInArray(myArray, Cells(iCell, 2)) Then
            ReDim Preserve myArray(0 To 1, 0 To cnt)
            myArray(0, cnt) = Cells(iCell, 1)
            myArray(1, cnt) = Cells(iCell, 2)
            cnt = cnt + 1
        End If
    Next iCell
End Sub

Function IsInArray(myArray As Variant, val As String) As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer, found As Boolean
    found = False

    If Not Len(myArray(0, 0)) > 0 Then
        found = False
    Else
        For i = 0 To UBound(myArray, 2)
            If myArray(0, i) = val Then
               found = True
               Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    End If
    IsInArray = found
End Function
```

Edited to include @PatrickLepelletier's suggestion and exit the loop after "found = true".

Comment: after `found=true`, you can add `exit for`