# Delete duplicates within an array in vba Excel

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, excel-2010

I've got values inside an array and I would like to delete the values with are double entries, e.g. I have EUR,EUR,EUR,GBP,YEN and I like to remove the double euro entries within removing them from the execel spreadsheet.

Just save then in an array. The new array should look like that: EUR,GBP,YEN

After that I would like to write them to another spreadsheet.

My code so far:

```
Dim ArrayCurrency As Variant
RangeStart = "E2"
RangeEnd = "E"
RangeNew = RangeStart & ":" & RangeEnd & lRow
CurrencyArray = Range(RangeNew).Value

For Each element In CurrencyArray

Next element
```

I hope that you can help me!

Best regards
Matthias

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11870095/vba-remove-duplicates-from-array

Answer (score 0):

Use Dictionary object for unique values - in the future.

For your current case, you may use [RemoveDuplicates method on the range.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh128798%28v=office.14%29.aspx#odc_office14_qn_RemoveDuplicates_TesttheSolution)

Comment: thank you for your answer! But I don't know how I can use a dictionary whitin vba? could you give an example?

Comment: As said that's for future. But did you try the answers tag in the above comment? Those include dictionary object.