# How to Delete rows according to criteria in cells

Tags: excel, vb.net

I am trying to automate some date filtering for work. 
I want to delete rows if they do not fall under this time stamp

2:00am - 10:00am

So if the time is before 2:00am or after 10:00am delete the entire row.
There are multiple rows like this.

I am not sure where to even start because I am very beginner and need an easy code to follow.

[Here is what the data would look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYxvr.png)

Comment: You're asking how to complete step 12 when it would seem you want to skip 1-11

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow @Moogurl - Did you try any VBA?  Perhaps start with the macro recorder and go from there?  If you can share some attempts and report back with specific issues - people will be more able and eager to help.

Comment: @Mr.Tripodi what do you mean skip 1-11?

Comment: @RugsKid hey I actually tried macro recorder but it doesnt make sense. Because some of the times arent there? let me try again.

Comment: @Moogurl My apologies, for some reasons I was thinking that you wanted to delete rows from a table, such as executing sql command.

Comment: @Mr.Tripodi nope. I want to basically scan the F column and delete times according to the scan. But not sure How this is achieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is similar to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11870095/vba-remove-duplicates-from-array/56169891#56169891) where I gave a similar answer. You can give this a try, though this assumes your times are in the 24 hour format and assumes you only want to delete that specific cell and not the entire row.

```vb
Sub TimeDelete()
 'Declare your variables
 Dim timeRng As Range, early As Long, late As Long, lrow As Long 

'Finds the last row with a time in it in Column F
 lrow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row 

 'Define the times you want to compare against
 early = "02:00:00"
 late = "10:00:00"

 'Specifies the range the times are in
 Set timeRng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(1,6), Cells(lrow,6))

 'Use a For loop to check each value in the range
 For Each Cell In timeRng.Cells
     If TimeValue(Cell.Value) >= TimeValue(early) And TimeValue(Cell.Value) <= TimeValue(late) Then
         Cell.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft 'Deletes cell if it meets the criteria and shifts remaining cells in the row to the left.
     End If
 Next Cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

My VBA is a bit rusty, but this should work

```
        Sub DelStuff()
        Dim WB As Workbook
        Dim Sheet As Worksheet
        Set WB = ActiveWorkbook
        Set Sheet = WB.ActiveSheet

        For Each r In Sheet.UsedRange.Rows

            If Cells(r.Row, "F").Value <= Date & " " & #2:00:00 AM# Or Cells(r.Row, "F").Value >= Date & " " & #10:00:00 AM# Then
                r.EntireRow.Delete
            End If

        Next r

        End Sub
```