# How to split string and store unique values into array

Tags: excel, vba

Can somebody help me to create an excel vba code below

For each cell in column 2 "Sequence", I want to split an string by a comma "," and store unique string in an array and populate the result in column 4!

Sorry, I can't attach a photo, there is an error, below is the details.

```
column 2
row 1 - R001,R002,R003,R004
row 2 - R003,R004,R005,R006
row 3 - R006,R009,R010,R011

column 4 (result should be)
row 1 - R001
row 2 - R002
row 3 - R003
row 4 - R004
row 5 - R005
row 6 - R006
row 7 - R009
row 8 - R010
row 9 - R011
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried, and where you have run into problems. It might help to read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: First, your "attached photo" seems to be missing. Secondly, can you show us what you have tried to accomplish this, and where you have gotten stuck? If you haven't made an attempt to solve your own problem, [you will likely get downvoted](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) and might not receive an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I cant attach a photo, I dont know why. I edited the description.

Answer (score 2):

For fun, I wanted to see if this could be done with worksheet formulas.

If you happen to have `O365` with the `FILTERXML`  and `TEXTJOIN` functions, you can use the formula below:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(",",,$A$1:$A$3),",","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[not(. = preceding::*)]"),ROWS($1:1)),"")
```

Algorithm:

- Join the relevant cells with a `comma` delimiter
- Create an XML from the text, with the commas separated the nodes.
- Use the `xPath` argument to only return a node if it is not preceded by an identical node

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Check out following links

[Split function](https://trumpexcel.com/vba-split-function/)

[Removing duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11870095/remove-duplicates-from-array-using-vba)

Comment: This is helpful but should be a comment instead