# Remove duplicates from a FIELD in SQL table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a situation where records imported into an access database contain some duplicates values in a specific field.  I do not want to remove any rows in the table with duplicates, rather just the duplicate values in the specific field in the relevant rows.  I tried a building a query around a kind of split in string but is hasn't worked. How do I process this?

Example of rows in table currently

[image]

What I need to achieve

[image]

Comment: You will need to write a VBA function for this.  MS Access is not sufficiently powerful.

Comment: I do NOT see duplicates!

Comment: As Gordon wrote, you need VBA. Per row: Split(), Dedupe, Join(), write back. I like https://stackoverflow.com/a/56594672/3820271 for Dedupe.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for response.  yes, I have created an EXCEL VBA procedure to stop this occurring again before the import.  Just need to deal with ones that have slipped past before now.  What about using SQL Server?  is it possible to do in SQL server?

Comment: @MaciejLos Rows 3, 6 and 8 have duplicate values within the field

Answer (score 0):

Take a deep look at your data...

If there's a duplicate within a field, every occurance of string is separated by `, ,`.

I'd suggest to create custom function as is described [here](https://www.devhut.net/2018/04/22/access-using-split-in-a-query/)

```
Public Function String_Split(sInput As String, _
                      lIndex As Long, _
                      Optional sDelim As String = ", ,") As String
    On Error GoTo Error_Handler
 
    String_Split = Split(sInput, sDelim)(lIndex)
 
Error_Handler_Exit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Exit Function
 
Error_Handler:
    String_Split = "Error!"
    Resume Error_Handler_Exit
End Function
```

Then, use it in [update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/update-statement-microsoft-access-sql) query:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET [Needs Details] = String_Split([Needs Details], 0)
```

If you want to preview the result of `String_Split` function, before you run `update` query, use this:

```
SELECT [Pupil Ref], [Needs Details], String_Split([Needs Details], 0) NewDetails
FROM  YourTable
```

That's all!

Answer (score 0):

You have duplication based on ", ," so if you find where that happens then take the left from that point.

Base your query on this:

```
select *,  iif(instr(field1,", ,")>1,  left(field1,instr(field1,", ,")-1), field1)
from table1
```

Comment: I was going to do so much more for you but I got tired of working with Access. But basically... create a new table with the same columns and use the above query to insert records into it.